# How can I make my jQuery 'Click' function run for the only the immediate li, and not the child li's

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got:

$('#accordion > li).click(function () {

But it run's if the #accordion li ol li is clicked as well.

Here's the html markup:

```
<ul id="accordion"> 
   <li id="test1">
       <a href="#">Test</a>
       <ol>
            <li>
            <a href="#">test</a>     
            </li>
       </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ended up finding a workaround to fix this:
    $('#accordion > li > a').click(function () {
To target the immeadiate a tag, and then using parent('li'), to do my actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the events on the descendant elements bubble up to the ancestor element.  Stop this by checking whether the originating element's  (`event.target`) first ancestor `li` is the one where the function is being handled:

```
$('#accordion > li').click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('li').is(this)) {
        // it's the right one
    }
});
```

See

- [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target)
- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

Comment: This is another good way to fix it, thank you.

I used a combination of $('#accordion > li > a').click(function () { 
and parent('li') to resolve it in the end

Answer (score 0):

You could use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) from jquery to avoid it bubbling up.

```
$('#accordion > li).click(function (event) {
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     //do what you need to do

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution might be:

```
$('#accordion > li:not(li li)').click(function () {});
```